# My JSP template is not rendering my custom Java object defined in my spring controller. How do I include a custom object in JSP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm quite new to java, spring, and JSP.  I've written a custom java class and manually defined of few instances of it.  I've put these instances into an ArrayList of objects, but when I try to include this list in my model, it is not rendering properly through jsp.

spring-controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getdata() {
    
    List<Post> list = getList();

    //return back to index.jsp
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("views/index");
    model.addObject("lists", list);

    return model;
}
class Post{
    private String type;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String likes;

    public Post(String type, String title, String content, String likes){
        this.type=type;
        this.title=title;
        this.content=content;
        this.likes=likes;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public String getContent(){
        return content;
    }
    public String getLikes(){
        return likes;
    }
}

private List<Post> getList() {

    List<Post> list = new ArrayList<Post>();
    
    Post post1 = new Post("1", "post 1", "post 1 cont", "3");
    Post post2 = new Post("1", "post 2", "post 2 cont", "12");
    Post post3 = new Post("2", "post 3", "post 3 cont", "0");
    Post post4 = new Post("3", "post 4", "post 4 cont", "1000");

    list.add(post1);
    list.add(post2);
    list.add(post3);
    list.add(post4);

    return list;

}

}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ include file="../partials/taglibs.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <jsp:include page="../partials/head.jsp"/>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <c:if test="${not empty lists}">
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">
                <li>${listValue.title}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>

    </c:if>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get a server status code 500 in the browser, and the following error:
Property [title] not readable on type [com.luwojtaszek.springbootjsp.web.controller.HomeController$Post@36130bcf]

If I remove the title property from the JSP file like so:

```
<c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">
      <li>${listValue}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

I get rid of the 500 server error, but my unordered list is nonsense:

- com.luwojtaszek.springbootjsp.web.controller.HomeController$Post@36130bcf
- com.luwojtaszek.springbootjsp.web.controller.HomeController$Post@5fed3595
- com.luwojtaszek.springbootjsp.web.controller.HomeController$Post@19cc95b
- com.luwojtaszek.springbootjsp.web.controller.HomeController$Post@88dd87d

So it seems that four things are indeed being sent in the list that I've created.  The problem is that I have done something wrong, and either the controller or JSP cannot work with it.

All I am trying to do is display some test data so that I can manipulate it with js.

How do I use a custom object with JSP?

P.S. the indentation is actually fine, stack overflows editor is terrible.

Comment: Is `Post` a public class?

Comment: Also where is `com.luwojtaszek.springbootjsp.web.controller.HomeController$Post@36130bcf` being printed from? I can not see it in your code (and BTW it is not nonsense as you have not overridden`toString`)

Comment: `500 server error` indicates that there is a server side exception - check your logs

Comment: @ScaryWombat making the class public fixed the issue.  I also went ahead and overwrote the toString method.  Sorry for such a basic question, but I'm coming from python for the most part.  I've been thrown into a java project at work and I'm trying to familiarize myself with it.  I'll write up an answer and accept it.

Comment: Good stuff, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Post class needed to be public.  This fixed the issue.  Thank you Scary Wombat!